# Any vector field is the sum of two complete vector fields

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

How can I show that any smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ is the sum of two complete vector fields?

Hint: the constant function $1$ on $M$ may be written as the sum of two non-negative functions with the property that the support of each of them is a disjoint union compact sets. (Why? and How?)

Comment: what have you tried? What is a complete vector field for you?

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik . The first, I think that partition of unity is very useful for my problem but I need its detai exactlyl. The second, you may look at "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field" for the definition of a complete vector field on a smooth manifold. Thanks.

Comment: "The first, I think that partition of unity is very useful for my problem but I need its detai exactlyl" This does not say "how" you have tried..